# Get and append current selection

Tags: javascript

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n78mkt3x/ which is extracted from w3school and what it does is filter elements. What I want to do now is to be able to get the current selection and append it in a `<p>` tag

Comment: Hope this helps, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/eYpePJq .. You can append the textContent to ```p``` tag inside JS itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set innerText by add in `filterSelection` method

`document.getElementById("current").innerText =`Current selection: ${c}`;`

JSfidder

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/2Lug34s8/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
elem = document.getElementById("current");
elem.innerText = "Current selection: " + c.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, m => m.toUpperCase())
```

Updated JS fiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/technochamp/5ev9mcnb/4/